# Как получить тип файла в PHP

Tags: php

Есть ссылка, указывающая на какой-то файл. Получаю содержимое файла через `file_get_contents()`. В ссылке явно не указан тип файла(в расширении), но мне нужно его получить. То есть узнать, к примеру zip, pdf, txt, doc или любой другой тип файла.

Comment: Сам нашел решение проблемы. Использовать функцию get_headers(). В заголовках есть название файла.

Comment: Use CURL, luke

Answer (score 3):

Для php 5.3+

```
<?php
function getUrlMimeType($url) {
     $buffer = file_get_contents($url);
     $finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
     return $finfo->buffer($buffer);
}
?>
```

[источник](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.finfo-buffer.php)

Для php `<` 5.3 не нашел, ибо даже родное `get_mime_type` ориентируется на расширение.

*`<sarcasm>`* Ну и вы всегда можете (например, если вы еще очень молоды и/или у вас совсем нет личной жизни) написать эвристический анализатор, который будет по первым буквам, специфическим подстрокам и тому подобному определять тип файла) *`</sarcasm>`*

Comment: Такой анализатор уже есть, в man file описан :)

Answer (score -1):

Первый способ годится для скриптов для PHP версии ниже 5.0. Вот он:

```
$ext = (($p = strrpos($filename,'.')) !== false)?substr($filename,$p+1):'';
```

Второй случай годится для PHP5+

```
$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

Comment: Не получается такими способами извлечь расширение, т.к. в названии файла его нет. Ссылка типа example.com/?docid=278279

Comment: По идентификатору **docid**, вы получаете имя файла из БД?

Comment: Этот файл находится на внешнем сервере и о нем ничего неизвестно.

Comment: ??? Если вы используете функцию **file_get_contents()**, то в обязательном порядке должны указать файл/путь к файлу. Разве это нельзя использовать?

Comment: echo file_get_contents("http://example.com/?docid=278279");
Так я получаю содержимое файла, но о его типе я ничего не знаю и мне нужно его определить.

Answer (score -1):

```
substr(strrchr($filename, '.'), 1);
```